# How do I assign a null value to a key which already has a existing value. I need to assign null value to a key because it satisifed a condition

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

based on a condition which says that if customer name from both tables match then few columns from one of the table should be assigned as **`null`**.I have all the input which which matches the condition, but I am not able to set the required columns as **`null`**

Input:

```json
[
  {
    "IN_num": "3",
    "In_Details": "404 error",
    "customer_name": "vivo",
    "customer_location": "hyd",
    "customer_ID": "1003"
  },
  {
    "IN_num": "2",
    "In_Details": "404 error",
    "customer_name": "MI",
    "customer_location": "hyd",
    "customer_ID": "1002"
  },
  {
    "IN_num": "1",
    "In_Details": "notworking",
    "customer_name": "Nokia",
    "customer_location": "Hyd",
    "customer_ID": "1001"
  }
]
```

I have tried creating a fake null value and assign it to the required key but still I am getting the already existing value that the key already has.

My spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "N1": [
          "=isNull(@(1,customer_ID))",
          "NuLl"
        ],
        "N2": [
          "=isNull(@(1,customer_location))",
          "NotNuLl"
        ],
        "Condition": "=concat(@(1,N1),'_',@(1,N2))",
        "test": null
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "IN_num": "[&1].IN_num",
        "In_Details": "[&1].In_Details",
        "customer_name": "[&1].customer_name",
        "test": "[&1].test",
        "customer_location": "[&1].customer_location",
        "Condition": {
          "NuLl_NotNuLl": {
            "@2,test": "customer_location"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

here customer location has an existing value but I want it to be printed as "".

output that im getting:

```json
[
  {
    "IN_num": "3",
    "In_Details": "404 error",
    "customer_name": "vivo",
    "test": null,
    "customer_location": "hyd"
  },
  {
    "IN_num": "2",
    "In_Details": "404 error",
    "customer_name": "MI",
    "test": null,
    "customer_location": "hyd"
  },
  {
    "IN_num": "1",
    "In_Details": "notworking",
    "customer_name": "Nokia",
    "test": null,
    "customer_location": "Hyd"
  }
]
```

for the key ""customer_location" I want the value to be "" or null.

how to proceed with this?

Comment: Well, what's your expected output, can you add it to the question as well please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about your expected result. If you are looking for a condition like if else statement then the below spec can help you.

```
[
{
"operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
"spec": {
  "*": {
    "N1": ["=isNull(@(1,customer_ID))", "NuLl"],
    "N2": ["=isNull(@(1,customer_location))", "NotNuLl"],
    "Condition": "=concat(@(1,N1),'_',@(1,N2))",
    "test": null
  }
}
}, {
"operation": "shift",
"spec": {
  "*": {
    "IN_num": "[&1].IN_num",
    "In_Details": "[&1].In_Details",
    "customer_name": "[&1].customer_name",
    "test": "[&1].test",
    "Condition": {
      "NuLl_NotNuLl": { //if
        "@2,test": "[&3].customer_location"
      },
      "*": { //else
        "@2,customer_location": "[&3].customer_location"
      }
    }
  }
}
}]
```

[image]

Let us know If you are looking for something different.

Comment: Please upvote and mark it as a correct answer

Comment: Thanks a lot praveen Kumar , this works perfectly :)